# Cohomology basics: relation between de Rham duality and Hodge duality.

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

Consider a product manifold $X=P \times P_{\perp}$, with $P$ and $P_{\perp}$ cycles of $X$, and let $\omega$ be the associated differential form of $P$ in the sense of de Rham duality (I suppose the correct words here are something like "let $\omega$ be a harmonic representative of the cohomology class of $P$").

Let $P^*$ be a cycle in the cohomology class which is de Rham dual to the Hodge dual of $\omega$, i.e to $* \omega$.

**Is it generally true $P^*$ and $P_{\perp}$ are in the same cohomology class?**

What I actually care about knowing is if $P^*$ and $P_{\perp}$ necessarily have the same volume.

---

The answer seems to be yes in the trivial example of a torus $X=T^2$, because the cohomology class of 1-cycles for which the 1-form $\omega=dx$ is a reprentatitive, is perpendicular to the cycles which are in the de Rham dual of $*\omega=dy$.

Further can any analogous statement can be made for manifolds which are not product manifolds?

I apologize for the very basic question (and any imprecisions in its formulation) - I have very little knowledge of cohomology. An answer which adressed my imprecisions in langugage would be especially instructive.

Comment: Start by learning Poincaré duality. This is purely topological. Your Hodge star construction depends on the choice of Riemannian metric.

Comment: What do you mean by DeRham duality?

Comment: @TedShifrin I mean that  deRham cohomology is the set of equivalence classes of closed forms on $X$ with equivalence of forms is they differ by an exact form, and de Rham's theorem gives an isomorphism between the deRham cohomology and the cohomology of chains on $X$. I am aware that the Hodge star is metric dependent, however at least my question about the equality of volumes is well defined (for a fixed choice of metric), no?

Comment: For starters, the Hodge star of a closed form need not be closed.

Comment: @TedShifrin right okay, I forgot to specify that I want $\omega$ to be a harmonic representative of the de Rham cohomology.  Fixed formulation. Perhaps now my question about the volumes is well defined? 

(apologies, i am coming from a physics background and have not had a chance to formally study cohomology yet).